# Linked List - How to make a recursive Adding method that add and " sort "?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

Hello i'm creating my own my linked list without implementing java.util.linkedlist

I want to create **a recursive** adding method that :

- should add a Pokemon whose level is between a pokemon who is lower level and higher level 
  Something like this :

Bulbasaur(5) -> Squirtle(15) -> Charmander(20)

then add(Pigeon) whose level is 6 so :

Bulbasaur(5) -> Pigeon(6) -> Squirtle(15) -> Charmander(20)

Adding pigeon is the part where I'm struggling

So far, i've managed to sort them because I've been adding them from the smallest to the biggest :

d1.addPokemon(p1); // level 5

d1.addPokemon(p2); // level 15

d1.addPokemon(p3); //level 20

d1.addPokemon(p4); // level 6 - Not adding, there is something wrong with my method I don't know what to change

Thank you

```
        public class Trainer{

            public final String name;
            private Pokeball head;

            public Trainer(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void display() {
                System.out.print(this.name + " : ");
                this.head.display();
            }

            public void addPokemon(Pokemon pok) {
                if (this.head != null) {
                    this.head.addPokemon(this.head, pok);
                } else {
                    this.head = new Pokeball(pok);
                }
            }

        }

        public class Pokeball {

            private Pokemon pok;
            private Pokeball next;

            public Pokeball(Pokemon pok) {
                this.pok = pok;
            }

  public Pokeball addPokemon(Pokeball current, Pokemon pok) {

        if (current == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (current.pok.getLevel() > pok.getLevel()) {
            Pokeball newPokeball = new Pokeball(pok);
            newPokeball.next = current;
            return newPokeball;
        }
        // if next is null add it to next
        if (current.next == null) {
            current.next = new Pokeball(pok);
        }
        // if next is not null and value is between two sequences add it between
        else if (pok.getLevel() > current.pok.getLevel() && pok.getLevel() <= current.next.pok.getLevel()) {
            Pokeball newPokeball = new Pokeball(pok);
            newPokeball.next = current.next;
            current.next = newPokeball;
        }
        // If value is not between call recursion again
        else {
            addPokemon(current.next, pok);

        }
        return current;
    }
        public class Pokemon {

            private String name;
            private int level;

            public Pokemon(String name, int level) {
                this.name = name;
                this.level = level;

            }

            public void display() {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print(this.name + " : " + this.level);

            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public int getLevel() {
                return level;
            }

            public void setLevel(int level) {
                this.level = level;
            }

        }

        public class test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                Pokemon p1 = new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", 5);
                Pokemon p2 = new Pokemon("Squirtle", 15);
                Pokemon p3 = new Pokemon("Charmander", 20);
                Pokemon p4 = new Pokemon("Pigeon", 6);

                Trainer t1 = new Trainer("Pierre");
                t1.addPokemon(p1);
                t1.addPokemon(p2);
                t1.addPokemon(p3);
                t1.addPokemon(p4);

                t1.display();

        // prints :
        Pierre : 
        Bulbasaur : 5 
        Squirtle : 15 
        Charmander : 20 
    // But pigeon is not here ! :(

            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't see addPokemon() of Dresseur

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I've edited now 
my variables were in french, I forgot to change this one

Comment: Is there any obligation about implementing the `add` method in a recursive form? Since always you have a sorted list and when you want to find the correct position to add the new Pokemon you can do it without recursion and very clear.

Comment: Hello, It is my exercise telling me to do it only in recursive form

Comment: @Russiancold Ahh, why did you delete your post ? I needed to do it in recursive way but I think I can also learn something new from iterative

Comment: I updated the answer, but in the case new Pokeball is the smallest level, it is added in Trainer class addpokemon method

Comment: One of your old old edit actually worked, the new updated answer works too and feels less "overwhelming" thank you very much

Comment: @Blebhebhe actually it doesn't correspond to SO rules since you asked for recursive method so my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change addPokemon method in `Pokeball` class like this.

```
 public void addPokemon(Pokeball current, Pokemon pok) {
     // if next is null add it to next
     if (current.next == null){
         current.next = new Pokeball(pok); 
     }
    // if next is not null and value is between two sequences add it between
    else if( pok.getLevel() > current.pok.getLevel() && pok.getLevel()<= 
    current.next.pok.getLevel()) {
       Pokeball newPokeball =  new Pokeball(pok);  
       newPokeball.next = current.next;
       current.next = newPokeball;
    } 
  // If value is not between call recursion again
   else {
      addPokemon(current.next, pok);
   }
```

}

At Trainer class change `addPokemon` method;

```
 public void addPokemon(Pokemon pok) {
        if (this.head != null) {
            if(pok.getLevel()<this.head.pok.getLevel()){
                Pokeball newPokeball = new Pokeball(pok);
                newPokeball.next = this.head;
                this.head = newPokeball;
                return;
            }
            this.head.addPokemon(this.head, pok);
        } else {
            this.head = new Pokeball(pok);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you explain why to do so?

Comment: I think the case of pok beeing the first isn't covered, but i think its a flaw in the design, since you have no acces to head of trainer

Comment: @Turo  I think It is covered in Trainer class addPokemon method. I wrote the answer directly here, did not test if its working.

Comment: Thank you It works great ! But as Turo said, what if Pigeon were level 4 ? 
I've tried to solve this problem first but gave up, I'm not sure how I modify the value head of Trainer from Pokeball

Comment: It's not covered in Trainer class, so it must be added there or give a pokomon/pokoball access to its trainer

Comment: @Blebhebhe  I updated the answer but I cannot try the code. What you should do is update the head in the trainer class if the newly added pokemon goes to first place.

Comment: Without adding Pigeon, Bulbasaur gets removed 
d1.addPokemon(p1);
  d1.addPokemon(p2);
  d1.addPokemon(p3);  but only squirtle and charmander are printed

Comment: AHH, I went through your edit and there was one solution that is working correctly. In my test, I was pretty sure It worked before your new edit 
I'll edit my post to put the correct solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's simply iterate through the list and every time check if the next node is more than a new one. The most straight way is:

```
public void addPokemon(Pokemon pokemon) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Pokeball(pokemon, null);
        return; 
    }
    Pokeball current = head;
    while(current.getPokemon().getLevel() < pokemon.getLevel()) { 
        if(current.getNext() == null) {
            current.getNext() == new Pokeball(pokemon, null);
            return;
        } else {
            if (current.getNext().getPokemon().getLevel() > pokemon.getLevel()) {
                current.setNext(new Pokeball(pokemon, current.getNext()))
                return;
        }
    }
    return;
```

Don't forget to add needed getters and setters. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/7147393) why it's good practise. Also there are many other ways to implement this, don't forget that you can implement `Iterator` and `Comparable` and then use some java tools like `sort()` or `compareTo()`, but these ways are more sophisticated and are not needed here.